# What is the equivalent of "dead tree copy" for CDs?

Tags: phrase-requests

The expression "dead tree copy" is a slightly pejorative way of referring to a (physical) printed book, as opposed to an ebook.

I was wondering if there is a similar expression that could be applied to CDs, DVDs, Blu-ray discs and other physical media for music, movies or games.

Comment: What makes you think it is pejorative? As far as I can tell it is simple descriptive: some times dead trees are advantageous, sometimes not.

Comment: You mean digital copies vs CDs/DVDs/etc, where CDs/DVDs/etc would be the equivalent of the dead trees, right? You're not looking for CDs/DVDs/etc vs something older. The first answer made me wonder.

Comment: I added the phrase about ebooks to my question, hopefully that's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea:  you could use "dead dinosaur copy" by analogy to "dead tree copy".  (Discs are made of plastic which is made from petrochemicals which come from dinosaurs.)

Comment: I like this neologism, even if I don't think it's strictly accurate. Oil and stuff comes from mostly plant matter doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I figured the idea is pretty firmly ingrained out there.  Call it poetic license.  Or use "dead plankton copy" if want to be more accurate.

Comment: Coal comes from plants, oil comes from animals (in general, exceptions on both sides).

Comment: I know this is old, but: When discussing motor oil, car people sometimes talk about "dino oil" as the opposite of "synthetic oil", suggesting that it's made of dead dinosaurs vs. synthetically produced.

Answer (score 5):

I always refer to CDs, DVDs, etc as *physical media*. But that's more plainly descriptive, and I'm not sure it's a good analog for *dead tree copy*. The term seems to be used fairly commonly to describe the "outdated physical form" concept:

[The Decline and Fall of Physical Media Retailing: A Timeline](http://technologizer.com/2011/02/17/borders-bankruptcy/)

[Are you finished with physical media?](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13645_3-57335653-47/are-you-finished-with-physical-media/)

[Why I Already Miss Physical Media](http://www.time.com/time/business/article/0,8599,2087984,00.html)

Comment: +1 I always say "physical copy" but I did not realize it was common usage.

Answer (score 3):

You could go for "hard copy".  For something like a document, a soft copy is a digital file and a hard copy is one on paper (i.e. something that you can hold because it is "hard").  For music or a movie, I don't see any other interpretation of what a "hard copy" would mean other than a disc (although the nitpicky might object on the basis that a disc still stores digital files)

Answer (score 1):

I used to call those free AOL CDs that were everywhere "beer coasters."

Comment: I quite like this suggestion, it's sufficiently derogatory; beer coasters are round in shape; throwaway; cheap; and easily replaceable. *And* if I'm not mistaken, you're not the first to call CDs, or DVDs that. So +1 from me!

Comment: Yes, "coaster" is the first thing that came to mind when I saw the question title. People actually do (did?) use CDs without useful content as coasters. Applying the word to suggest that CDs/DVDs are entirely obsolete seems like a great fit.

Answer (score 0):

For music, you could refer to having it "on vinyl", i.e. on a record, but many people would not consider that pejorative.  If you specifically want to be demeaning about it, you might refer to the "8-track edition" of something; I don't know of anyone who considers the 8-track format decent.

For the other things (movies & games) there really isn't a "baseline" format like the 'dead-tree edition' of a printed book that's been around essentially forever;  about the best you can do is refer to some specifically outdated format like LaserDisc.